# How to provide parameter options in Dexie's WhereClause.inAnyRange(ranges, options)?

Tags: typescript, dexie

I am using [Dexie](https://dexie.org) (currently version 2.0.4) in my Typescript written project. Now I'd like to use [WhereClause.inAnyRange()](https://dexie.org/docs/WhereClause/WhereClause.inAnyRange()) and provide the parameter `options` as following

```
options.includeLowers = true
options.includeUppers = true
```

The type description of `dexie.d.ts` contains only the definition without a second parameter:

```
inAnyRange(ranges: Array<IndexableTypeArrayReadonly>): Collection<T, Key>;
```

How am I supposed to provide the options parameter correctly?

Comment: I only need one range so I could use [WhereClause.between()](https://dexie.org/docs/WhereClause/WhereClause.between()) where it was no problem providing the options `includeLower` and `includeUpper`.

Comment: I think you've discovered a typings bug in dexie. I filed the issue and fixing it for next release on the master branch (version 3.0 alpha). https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/issues/792